# Energy gap of infinite unidimensional atoms chain

Tags: solid-state-physics

Suppose you have two different types of atoms that alternate in an infinite 1 dimensional chain.

The distance between each atom is $\frac{a}{2}$. The first type of atom generates (in its reference frame) the potential $aV_0\delta(x)$, the second type generates (always in its reference frame) the potential $\frac{a}{2}V_0\delta(x)$. I need to calculate the first three energy gap between the first four bands. (assume nearly free electron model is valid)

I've tried to solve it this way: I have a lettice of the type $R_n=na$, the reciprocal lettice will be defined by $G_m=\frac{2\pi}{a}m$. The complessive potential generated by the atoms can be rewritten as:
\begin{align}
V(x)=\sum_naV_0\delta(x-na)+\frac{a}{2}V_0\delta[x+(n+\frac{1}{2})a]
\end{align}
To proceed to calculate the energy gaps I calculate the Fourier transform over the cell of the crystal:
\begin{align}
U_G=\frac{1}{a}\int_{cell} V(x)e^{-iG_mx}dx=V_0\int \delta(x-a)e^{-iG_mx}+\frac{1}{2}\delta(x-\frac{a}{2})e^{-iG_mx} dx
\end{align}
This integral is easily evaluated thanks to the Dirac's delta properties to be:
\begin{align}
U_G=V_0(e^{-iG_ma}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-iG_m\frac{a}{2}})=V_0(e^{-2\pi im}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-\pi im})=V_0(1+(-\frac{1}{2})^m)
\end{align}

So $U_G$ is $\frac{3}{2}V_0$ for even values of $m$ and $\frac{1}{2}V_0$ for odd values of $m$. I evaluate the energy gaps as follows:
\begin{align}
E_g=2|U_G|
\end{align}
That is:
\begin{align}
E_g(m=1)=V_0\\
E_g(m=2)=2V_0\\
E_g(m=3)=V_0\\
\end{align}

Could you please tell me if this is correct? I'm not sure if I'm definining the lettice the right way. I'm sorry if I used improper terminology or bad formatting.